# How do I batch copy and rename files with same name in different path?

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, file-handling

I have a set of folders, inside each folder I have several sub-folders. In each sub folder there is a file called result.txt I need all the result.txt to be copied to other location renaming result files.

folders:

```
 abc1
 efg1
 doc2
 ghih
```

sub-folders:
in `aaa1`

```
1.abc1.merged
2.abc1.merged
3.abc1.merged
4.abc1.merged
```

in `efg1`

```
1.efg1.merged
2.efg1.merged
3.efg1.merged
4.efg1.merged
5.efg1.merged
...
...
```

so on
all of the sub-folders contain result.txt in a single different folder with all the result files renamed to result1.txt,result2.txt etc.

I tried to  set name of sub-folder as a variable in shell script and made a loop to go in to the sub-folder and copy the result.txt to other path and rename it by mv command.But only the result.txt file from one subdirectory each is copied not the all.

I tried with following commands:

```
cp  $folder/$subfolder/resu*txt ../tsv/$newfolder/
```

(I previously assigned variables)

```
mv  ../tsv/$newfolder/resu*txt ../tsv/$newfolder/results$tts.txt
```

(I defined $tts as number of subfolders in the folder)

This copied the result.txt from only first sub-folder in each of parent folders.

Comment: [tag:batch-file] is related to Windows, so please adapt the tags! perhaps you meant [tag:spring-batch] or [tag:bash], or even [tag:batch-processing]?

Comment: batch-processing actually. I will correct that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say something like:

```
i=1
for dir in **/*;  # loop through files
do
    cp "$dir"/result.txt $your_path/result$i.txt
    ((i++))       # increment variable $i
done
```

The syntax `**/*` goes through all the subdirectories.

#### Test

```
$ mkdir a
$ cd a
$ mkdir a{1..4}
$ mkdir a{1..4}/a{1..4}
$ for f in **/*; do echo "$f --"; done
```

The last command returns

```
a1/a1 --
a1/a2 --
...
a4/a4 --
```